# $y=\frac{-4}{5} \cos(t) + \frac{8}{5} \sin(t)+(a+\frac{4}{5})e^{t/2}$ - Asymptotic behavior

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had solve the initial value problem $y'- \frac{y}{2}=2 \cos(t)$ with $y(0)=a \in \mathbb{R}$. The result is $y=\frac{-4}{5} \cos(t) + \frac{8}{5} \sin(t)+(a+\frac{4}{5})e^{t/2}$. How could I found the critical value $a_0$ of the parameter $a$ such that the asymptotic behavior of the solution change  abruptly?

Comment: Look at $a=-4/5$.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Why this value instead of the others?

Comment: I have written an answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Look at $a=-4/5$. There our function is basically a sine curve, for the exponential term vanishes.

For $a\gt -4/5$, $y$ blows up rapidly as $t$ gets large.  For $a\lt -4/5$, $y\to-\infty$ rapidly as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: the solution does not blow up; in fact it exists on $-\infty < t < \infty$

Comment: It does not blow up at a point, unless we count $\infty$ as a point. But for $a=-4/5$, the solution is bounded, while afterwards the solution goes to $\infty$ as $t\to\infty$, and beforehand it goes to $-\infty$.